# When using object pronouns, should I say "la van a ver a" or "la van a ver"?

Tags: verbos, pronombres

If I have a question:

¿Quiénes van a ver a Luisa el domingo?

I can answer it someway like this, using object pronoun (I do not know if this is the right way to say that in English):

Los alumnos van a verla el domingo.

But if I want to put "la" in front of the verb phrase:

Los alumnos la van a ver **a** el domingo.

Should I say the "a" in bold here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're close, but **no**, even though your `Los alumnos van a verla el domingo.` is correct, in the second case you should say:

> Los alumnos la van a ver **el** domingo

Comment: Oh, I made a mistake when typing ... just forgot the article el...then you mean the "a" should not be used here.

Comment: Oh, I see, but yes, the `a` has no place in your second sentence, because the `a` in the first one is part of `verla` so, `van a verla` is equivalent in this case to `la van a ver`